# How to trigger and capture HD video from DSLR

Tags: hardware, sd-card, camera

I am looking to do the following and am wondering what approach to use:

1. Trigger a DSLR into taking a 1080p video for a specified duration or start/stop
2. Remove the video file from the DSLR onto the RPI SD card

Basically I have two things to do here, remote trigger and remote transfer. I have found some ways to trigger video recording but am not sure about the transfer - which made me wonder if someone else has solved this already.

Comment: Depends on the camera.  I believe gphoto can talk to Canon cameras over USB.

Comment: Right yeah, can gphoto do triggering and pulling files off a camera? I'm going to buy a camera specially so it can be compatible with specific libraries etc.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.gphoto.org/doc/remote/ and http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php

Answer (score 2):

The MagPi, issue 6 (read: back in the olden days), had an article about the [Camera Pi](http://www.davidhunt.ie/raspberry-pi-in-a-dslr-camera/). It integrates a Pi in the battery grip of a Canon DSLR.

The camera's trigger is done via the shutter release port from a GPIO pin of the Pi. This also allows waking up from sleep modes (which could supposedly not be done via USB and `gphoto`). Readout of the captured image/video files is done via USB.